# Determine $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ and show that $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is non-abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, galois-theory

> Question: Let $K$ be a splitting field for $x^5-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}.$
>
> $(1)$ Determine $[K:\mathbb{Q}].$
>
> $(2)$ Show that $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is non-abelian.

---

For $(1),$ note that roots of $x^5-2$ are
$$\sqrt[5]{2}, \sqrt[5]{2}\omega, \sqrt[5]{2}\omega^2, \sqrt[5]{2}\omega^3, \sqrt[5]{2}\omega^4$$
where $\omega$ is the $5$th root of unity, that is,
$$\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}.$$
So we have
$$K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{2}, \omega),$$
implying that
$$[K:\mathbb{Q}] = [K:\mathbb{Q}(\omega)] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}] = 5 \times 4 = 20.$$

---

For $(2),$ I know that $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to the Dihedral group with $20$ elements.
Since such Dihedral group is non-abelian, so is $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}).$
However, I do now know how to prove it.

Comment: $|\Bbb Q(\omega):\Bbb Q|=4$.

Comment: Consider the action of the Galois group as permutations of the roots.

Comment: You can find two elements in the Galois group that don't commute.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Corrected it.

Comment: The Galois group is not dihedral.

Comment: This Galois group is not dihedral. It is isomorphic to the holomorph of $C_5$, i.e. the semi-direct product $C_5\rtimes Aut(C_5)=C_5\rtimes C_4$. The dihedral group of order twenty has a non-trivial center but the center of this group is trivial.

Comment: A way forward is to observe that an automorphism $\sigma$ is fully determined once you know $\sigma(\omega)$ and $\sigma(\root5\of2)$. There are four (resp. five) choices for those two images. Because we know that there will be twenty automorphisms, all combinations must occur exactly once. After that point you can identify the Galois group as a subgroup of the permutations of the five roots of $x^5-2$.

Comment: A hint for a shorter way of settling part (2): If the Galois group were abelian, then all its subgroups would be _____. Consequently all the intermediate fields would be _____ extensions of the rationals. But the extension $\Bbb{Q}(\root5\of2)/\Bbb{Q}$ is not _____, so this cannot be the case. The same word goes into all the blank spaces :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The missing word is normal.

Comment: Correct. Feel free to turn that into an answer :-)